# Multiple views for the same ViewModel

Tags: mvvmcross

Let's say I have a bunch of kittens. Perhaps I have a KittenViewModel. I want to show it as a kitten card in a card view, but also as broken down into columns in a list view. Does MvvmCross support binding the KittenViewModel to multiple views? Should I have multiple ViewModels that refer back to a single model?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer**: I know that I am replying to an old question which you may well have forgotten; this is for posterity. Also, I have limited understanding of the MVVM design pattern. I remember reading somewhere that Views and ViewModels are typically in 1-to-1 correspondence, so the conventional answer is probably "You shouldn't do that. Reconsider your design."

With that being said, I recently struggled with this for a while before coming up with a very simple solution that operates under the following assumptions: (1) you wish to use the exact same instance of a ViewModel in two separate Views; (2) for whatever reason, you cannot use a `DataTemplateSelector` to determine which View to use; and (3) you do not mind creating multiple Views for the same ViewModel.

The solution is to define separate data templates for the `KittenViewModel` as resources for whatever controls you are going to use to display the data. For example, if you have created a `KittenCardView` user control and intend to display it in a `ContentControl`, you can set the `DataTemplate` in a `ContentControl` resource, something like:

```
<ContentControl>
    <Control.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodel:KittenViewModel}">
            <view:KittenCardView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Control.Resources>
</ContentControl>
```

The `KittenColumnView` (or whatever you call it) would be handled similarly. You may find it helpful to define one of the Views as a Window or App resource if typically use one and only need the other in special circumstances.